# CSS :after is being pushed down by following elements

Tags: html, css, less

I'm using an `after` element to display a border under a `h2` element, but for some reason the `after` element is pushed down by the following `divs` / elements / text.

image explanation:
[image]

why is this happening? whats wrong with my code?

```
&:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    bottom:-20px;
    width: 200px;
    background: @yellow;
    content: '';

}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: May I suggest you create an example jfiddle to show more clearly the behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide working code snippet for the issue.

Comment: Seems more like scss than css

Comment: Please create a working example that reproduces the issue so it would be easier for us to help you with it.

Comment: thanks guys, sorry next time i'll provide a working example. Never used stackoverflow to ask something - so I still have to learn how to ask right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that position absolute in this case is not relative to its parent "H2" In order to fix that put

```
h2{
   position:relative;
}
```

```css
h2:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    bottom:-20px;
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    content: '';
} 
h2{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<h2>title</h2>
```

Comment: great it worked, please upvote, there are other options too, you could use margin bottom like is explained in Mrx's answer..

Comment: yeah I upvoted your answer - but my reputation is too low, so its not shown. and moving the border-bottom with margin is not exactly what I need, way better with an after element.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `border-bottom: 4px solid yellow;` css?

Comment: thanks for your answer - because I want to decide where the border is and how long it is